# ¿Cómo añadir más campos en comment_form de Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theme

En mi formulario de los comentarios de *Wordpress*, solo me aparece el campo de texto para escribir el comentario y el botón de publicar comentario. Quisiera añadir también el campo de texto del autor, email y el sitio web. ¿Cómo podría editarlo? He buscado en varios artículos y foros, y esto ha sido lo que he encontrado:

En el fichero **functions.php** he puesto esto:

```
function industria_modify_comment_fields( $fields ) {

    //Variables necesarias para que esto funcione
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    $fields =  array(

      'author' =>
        '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
        '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' placeholder="' . __('Tu nombre', 'industria') . '" />', //Editamos el campo autor

      'email' =>
        '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
        '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' placeholder="' . __('Tu email', 'industria') . '" />', //Editamos el campo email

      'url' =>
        '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
        '" size="30" placeholder="' . __('Tu sitio web', 'industria') . '"  />', //Editamos el campo sitio web
    ); 

    return $fields;
}
add_filter(
    'comment_form_default_fields', 
    'industria_modify_comment_fields'
);
```

Y en el fichero **comments.php** tengo esto:

```
comment_form(
    array(
        'title_reply' => __('Deja tu comentario', 'industria'), //Cambiar título
        'label_submit' => __('Publicar opinión', 'industria'), //Cambiar texto de botón
        'comment_field' => '<span>Comentario</span> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" placeholder="' . __('Escribe tu opinión...', 'industria') . '"></textarea>', //Borrar párrafo y label del textarea
        'comment_notes_before' => '', //Borrar las notas antes del formulario
        'comment_notes_after' => '' //Editar las notas después del formulario
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'custom_fields');
function custom_fields($fields) {

    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    $fields[ 'author' ] = '<p class="comment-form-author">'.
      '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label>'.
      ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ).
      '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="'. esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
      '" size="30" tabindex="1"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';

    $fields[ 'email' ] = '<p class="comment-form-email">'.
      '<label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label>'.
      ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ).
      '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="'. esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
      '" size="30"  tabindex="2"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';

        $fields[ 'url' ] = '<p class="comment-form-url">'.
          '<label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>'.
          '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="'. esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
      '" size="30"  tabindex="3" /></p>';

return $fields;
}
```

Puedes añadir más campos pero esos son los que pedías en la pregunta, espero haberte ayudado.
Antes de eso deberás crear un fichero llamado 'extendcomment.php' con el siguiente plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Extend Comment
Version: 1.0
Plugin URI: http://smartwebworker.com
Description: A plugin to add fields to the comment form.
Author: Specky Geek
Author URI: http://www.speckygeek.com
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues me sigue sin salir, me sale siempre lo que tengo puesto en el fichero comments.php, no soy capaz de modificar el formulario. Algo tendré mal seguro, pero no lo veo...